# Why do changes made to photos within the iOS simulator not persist?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, photolibrary, photokit

I've recently been working with Apple's Photos framework, when I noticed that any changes made to PHAssets don't actually persist - the photo library kind of "glitches out" and a blank, grey space is left in the thumbnail view within my app.

Upon opening the Photos app, the view "resets" the thumbnail, but displays the original photo, and not the modifications I made within my app. Further, going into the native "editing" mode within the photos app revealed that those modifications **were** acknowledged, as there was a red "Revert" button available. Tapping it did nothing (since the photo displayed was already the original photo).

I decided to investigate this further. Even within the native Photos app, any filters or changes (such as straightening, cropping, etc) are ultimately not reflected within the Photos app. The changes are made, and then when tapping "done", the image reverts by itself to the original image. **Changes are not kept!**

However, after testing my app on a device, the app works fine! Changes are reflected immediately, and no "glitches" occur! Very weird!

I've tried resetting the simulator, and reinstalling Xcode (my version is 7.2). It might be important to note I've also tried on different simulators (iOS 9.1 & 9.2). Any ideas on why this is happening? Is it being experienced by others? Please share!

Thanks for reading!

---

**UPDATE 1**
At one point after making changes within the native Photos app, tapping "Done" yielded the following error message:
"There was an error saving this photo. Please try again later."

Comment: I've encountered the same issues, it's just a Simulator problem. Please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Submitted successfully: 24295414